# Cannot unmarshall using @XmlAttribute

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I can marshall my sitemap with JAXB, though I cannot unmarshall it! Any help would be much appreciated.

I get the following exception:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
>   (uri:"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", local:"urlset").
>   Expected elements are <{}urls>,<{}urlset>

Sitemap urlset:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "urlset")
public class XMLURLSet
{
   List<XMLURL> urls;
   final String xmlns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";

   @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns")
   public String getXmlns() {
      return xmlns;
   }

   public void setXmlns(String xmlns) {
      // nop
   }

   @XmlElement(name = "url")
   public List<XMLURL> getUrls(){
      return urls;
   }

   public void setUrls(List<XMLURL> urls) {
      this.urls = urls;
   }
```

Sitemap urls:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "urls")
public class XMLURL {
   String loc;

   public String getLoc() {
      return loc;
   }

   public void setLoc(String loc) {
      this.loc = loc;
   }
}
```

Output XML (it's correct):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

JUnit marshalling code that works

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLURLSet.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(urlSet, sw);
String xml =  sw.toString();
```

Unmarshalling that DOESNT WORK (cont' from above):

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLURLSet.class);
Unmarshaller umsler = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
XMLURLSet xmlUrlSet = (XMLURLSet) umsler.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

The last line generates the exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9", local:"urlset"). Expected elements are <{}urls>,<{}urlset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are trying to namespace qualify your document.  You will need to add a class called `package-info` in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry:

**package-info**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package your.package.name;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html